# error for "apply" in kotlin on android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I was following a tutorial on android studio and wrote the following lines:

```
RecyclerView.apply {this:RecyclerView!
            var layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
```

but the "apply" was giving me an error and when I did Alt+Enter I saw two options for import that I did not really understand. they had to do with something called "auto-import" and i saw the word "gravity gradle". The suggestions went away for some reason after i messed around with the settings that came up, but the error is still there.

Comment: RecyclerView is a class; you can't call `apply` statically. If RecyclerView is an ID and you're using synthetics, or you decided to name the field that, please rename it now. The compiler may not be able to tell if you mean the variable or the class. If you used Kotlin synthetics, note that it's deprecated. Use your favorite search engine for alternatives. (You're looking for jetpack something, don't remember exactly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how `apply` works:

```
val recyclerView = RecyclerView(context)
recyclerView.adapter = MyAdapter()
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager()
recyclerView.hasFixedSize = true
```

vs

```
val recyclerView = RecyclerView(context).apply {
    adapter = MyAdapter()
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager()
    hasFixedSize = true
}
```

you run it on an instance of an object, which becomes `this` in the lambda, so you can do all the calls on the object without referring to it by name. And the original object pops out of the end, so you can assign the whole thing to `val recyclerView` - it gets the `RecyclerView()` you created, with a few settings `apply`ed to it. So it's common to configure objects like this.

So like people have said, you weren't calling `apply` on a `RecyclerView` *instance*, you were calling it on the class itself, which doesn't work. You need to create a thing. Kotlin synthetic binding is magic code that automatically creates objects for you, from the XML it inflates, and assigns them to a variable named after the view's ID in the XML. So your tutorial is referring to an instance, using a variable name that the synthetics declared in the background. It's confusing if you're not aware of it, and I wonder if that's part of the reason it's deprecated.

Sinner of the System's answer is the easiest (and normal) way to grab an object from your layout, by looking it up by ID yourself.

Answer (score 1):

"apply" is available to Any object in kotlin. You don't need to import anything to use "apply"

[Apply in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html)

But, if IDE is suggesting you to import anything for apply, that means kotlin library is not properly configured.

Check your app/build.gradle dependencies whether kotlin-stdlib exists or not.

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
```

Comment: thats why i was confused. But yea I just went into dependencies in Project Structure and saw  "implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"" listed. so that is probably not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

that is because RecyclerView is not an instance. You can't use "apply" on a class.

You may want to do something like this

```
val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.your_recycler)
recyclerView.apply {
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
}
```

Comment: i named my recyclerview the ID recyclerview and used that to call it. as part of following the tutorial.

Comment: what tutorial? You cant give a class name to an object

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jgYGrms5VA&t=666s 10:56 you can see

Comment: her recycler is called "restaurantsRecyclerView" not "RecyclerView". And he is using kotlin synthetics wihc are now deprecated. So you need create a variable before call "apply" as in my answer.

Comment: yea i changed the name, but I see now. So that was the issue?

Comment: Yes, the compiler resolve "RecyclerView" as a reference to the RecyclerView class. Only classes should have a capitalized name. But you should also read about [migrating from kotlin synthetics to view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration)